# NullPointerException at facesContext.getResponseWriter.write()

Tags: java, jsp

I am using `facesContext.getResponseWriter.write()` to display error messages but value of `getResponseWriter` is `null`. How to sort out this issue?

```
if(context != null){ 
    context.getResponseWriter().write(msg) ;
}

else{
    pageContext.getResponse().getWriter().write(
    "<div id='errorMsgsFromTag' style='position:absolute;visibility:hidden'>" + msg + "</div>"); 
}
```

setting message in msg String and getting context by

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
```